# How do I get the address of the last item in a row?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Assume we have this sheet with the following data as an example:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F | Column G | Column H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 | Foo | Bar | Syn | Ack | rand |

Beyond column H, no value exist. Is it possible to get the address of the last populated cell in the row?

I only know how to get the value which is: `=INDEX(Sheet!2:2,1,COUNTA(Sheet!2:2))`.

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
=Address(1,MATCH("zzz",1:1))
```

[image]